# data with video to text transcription

Tags: python, video

I search data and script (java, python) where from video, text is transcripted into documents.I.E recognize speech from video to text
i found this
https://github.com/Naki21/google-speech-to-text
but as i can see, it is google API and most likely it is paid and
it is not a fact that the quality will be acceptable.
Because the task is difficult, therefore I am looking for  free script where with video the text is recognized into  text document. 
Is there sometrhing about it on github or kaggle?
because even if the quality is poor, at least it is for free

Comment: youtube.com has a feature that auto-translates voice to text (when a specific transcription isn't given). It's not very good, but it might help.

Comment: I need script:)

Comment: Some youtube videos do have time linked scripts as well (ie, subtitle files), and, of course, there's always closed captioning.